# How to Encode/Decode unicode like git does?

Tags: node.js, git, perl, unicode, utf-8

At git when `core.quotepath = on`

`魔神転生2.CT` will Convert to `\351\255\224\347\245\236\350\273\242\347\224\2372.CT`

how to decode/encode at perl or nodejs?

---

why i wanna do this?

cos i have a old perl script for git

but when i use `core.quotepath = off`

my perl script can't handle unicode

it will become `擳?頠Ｙ?2.CT` or `矇簫?癟瞼?癡罈瞽癟??2.CT`

at nodejs utf8 work well, but somehow it fail when i exec some git cmd

like `git commit -m . --dry-run --short`

---

[this is my old perl script](https://github.com/bluelovers/git_env/blob/master/msysgit/local/bin/git-lazy-ci)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s{\\(\d{3})}{ chr(oct($1)) }eg`. The result is UTF-8. If you want Unicode Code Points, follow up with `decode_utf8`.

---

You might need to handle other escape sequences too.

```
my %escapes = (
   "n"  => "\n",
   "r"  => "\r",
   # ...
);

s{\\(?:([0-7]{3})|(\W)|(\w))}{
   defined($1) ? chr(oct($1)) :
   defined($2) ? $2 :
   $escapes{$3} // do { warn("Unrecognized escapes \\$3"); "\\$3" }
}seg;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an awesome plugin for node.js [Unicode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unicode)

```
# debian
sudo apt-get install unicode-data # optional
# gentoo
sudo emerge unicode-data # optional

npm install unicode
```